# Moving to new server, now CodeIgniter / Ion_Auth are not working

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli, ion-auth

So I am moving to a new host server. One of my school projects that is in use on the old server must remain up with no downtime, so I am prepping the new server and moving over all the files associated. I've got the virtual host all set up and working, now CodeIgniter and Ion_Auth don't seem to be working.

I am getting the dreadful white screen of death. Here's what I have done so far and in order.

First, CodeIgniter was looking for the Ion_Auth library under 'core/MY_Ion_Auth.php' so after research I found that I needed to change the __autoload() function (application/config/config.php l# 385) FROM

```
function __autoload($class)
{
    if(strpos($class, 'CI_') !== 0)
    {
        @include_once( APPPATH . 'core/'. $class . EXT );
    }
}
```

TO

```
function __autoload($class)
{
    if (strpos($class, 'CI_') !== 0)
    {
        if (file_exists($file = APPPATH . 'core/' . $class . EXT))
        {
            include $file;
        }

        elseif (file_exists($file = APPPATH . 'libraries/' . $class . EXT))
        {
            include $file;
        }
    }
}
```

And it was a success. My script no longer broke after the autoload. Now, I am still getting a white screen but my log file is showing different errors.

Here's my log file:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); ?>
ERROR - 2015-01-29 11:55:15 --> Severity: Notice  --> Undefined variable: user /var/www/CIS411-GIS_Conference/application/views/templates/menubar.php 36
ERROR - 2015-01-29 11:55:15 --> Severity: Notice  --> Trying to get property of non-object /var/www/CIS411-GIS_Conference/application/views/templates/menubar.php 36
ERROR - 2015-01-29 11:55:15 --> Severity: Notice  --> Undefined variable: user /var/www/CIS411-GIS_Conference/application/views/templates/menubar.php 39
ERROR - 2015-01-29 11:55:15 --> Severity: Notice  --> Trying to get property of non-object /var/www/CIS411-GIS_Conference/application/views/templates/menubar.php 39
```

Now, the 'undefined variable' is supposed to be undefined. It is in an if statement checking to see if the user is logged in first (which I am not) therefore, this code shouldn't even be running!

Here's the menubar.php if statement:

```
<?
    if ($this->ion_auth->logged_in()) {
        // Get users info
        $user = $this->ion_auth->user()->row();
        // Display account links
?>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><?=$user->email?> <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <li <? if(is_active('auth/dashboard')): ?>class="active"<? endif; ?>><a href="<?= site_url('auth/dashboard') ?>">Dashboard</a></li>
          <li <? if(is_active('auth/edit_user')): ?>class="active"<? endif; ?>><a href="<?= site_url('auth/edit_user/'.$user->id) ?>">Account Settings</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="<?= site_url('auth/logout') ?>">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

All that said, still getting the WSOD and not sure what to do next. 
I did have to change from mysql to mysqli due to pconnect no longer being supported by PHP5.x. I'm thinking this could have something to do with it but have no idea how to go about fixing it.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: To take out the doubts, after `$this->ion_auth->logged_in()` do the following `echo "Look, I'm actually inside the condition..";` and see what happens..

Comment: I put it in there and still a white page. It is not rendering anyhing. The lines #'s in the log file correspond to      $user->email      and      $user->id

Comment: Then add `return` right after `if($this->ion_auth->logged_in()){` and see if the log file continues to output the error. Don't forget to take a look at the time of the file.

Comment: Still gives me the same error in the log file. Undefined variable: user. I also tried taking out the if statement completely which resulted in no errors, but still the WSOD

Comment: I really doubt that. Unless you're not showing us the correct code, the `return` should stop from giving you the errors. Your error is somewhere else or you haven't placed `return` correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure "output_buffering" is on in your PHP.ini